# Azure Blob Go lib using the TokenCredential to access the blob api always return error

Tags: azure, go, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use the azblob go libary to access the blob storage using the service principal, I found one one API:
https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob#NewTokenCredential
It seems that it can take the OAuthToken from Adal lib, but I always get this error: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

```
oauthConfig, err := adal.NewOAuthConfig(env.ActiveDirectoryEndpoint, tenantID)
spt, err := adal.NewServicePrincipalToken(*oauthConfig, clientID, clientSecret, "https://storage.azure.com/")    
creds := azblob.NewTokenCredential(spt.OAuthToken(), nil)
blobPipeline := azblob.NewPipeline(creds, azblob.PipelineOptions{})
url := azblob.NewContainerURL(*URL, blobPipeline)
_, err := url.ListBlobsHierarchySegment(...)
```

If I swith the NewTokenCredential with the SharedKeyToken, then the code can run properly, but we can not use SharedKeyToken in our env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is it seems as though Authentication has taken place successfully so your use of the ADAL library seems fine.

The most likely cause of this is that the principal that you're using to authenticate to Azure Active Directory with does not have the necessary permissions to access the blobs in the storage account.

You'll need to sign in to the Azure Portal, find and select the storage account in question, then:

1. Select **Access Control (IAM)**
2. Go to **Role assignments**
3. Click on the **Add** button
4. From the **Role** scroll down to **Storage Blob...** and select one of the storage blob roles to suite your requirements
5. In the **Select** textbox type part of the principal's name for which you are obtaining a token for via ADAL
6. Click the **Save** button

Once completed, try running your app again.  The token may need to be refreshed so ensure your authentication and token retrieval code is rerun.

Comment: that is my initial guess too, but I did use the Service Principal and tried it with `az cli` and az cli can do the operation on that container with this same service principal.

Comment: Doesn't your az cli ask you to login through a browser? If so then the cli will impersonate whichever identity you logged in with not the service account identity so you may be able to perform the operation in cli but the service account may not.

Comment: you can use service account to login via az cli
`az login --service-principal -u  <appid> -p <secret>  -t <tenant_id>`
using this, you will not need to login via browser, it will assume role using your service principal.

Comment: I believe I saw earlier in your ADAL implementation you were using "http://storage.azure.net" or something in one of your calls.  Could you check and ensure this is set to the base URI of your actual storage account URI?

Comment: I replace "storage.azure.net" with my storage account uri like this: "https://ruidev.blob.core.windows.net"
and still got the same error.

Comment: Can you view the token you've got back in spt.OAuthToken() ? It should be a string or byte array 1159 characters long.

Comment: the auth token I am getting is only 1154 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up create a service request ticket for Azure, and they responded with a sample code here for auth with Azure using golang:
https://github.com/google/go-cloud/blob/master/blob/azureblob/example_test.go#L111